# Tables in JTextPane and cell spanning (cell merging)

Tags: java, swing, tabular, jeditorpane

I have a question. I need to know, if it is possible to insert table in [`JEditorPane`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/text.html) (I have found an example at http://java-sl.com/JEditorPaneTables.html) without using HTML and to use the column and row spanning cells. In short I need to insert a table like this:

```
+-------+--------+-------+
| first | second | third |
+-------+--------+-------+
| c1    | col. spanning  |
+-------+--------+-------+
| c2    |        | c3    |
+-------+ row s. +-------+
| c4    |        | c5    |
+-------+--------+-------+
```

I tried to *google* it, but I nowhere have found, what I am looking for. The question of the spanning cells is perhaps not so common.

Comment: What is preventing the use of HTML?

Comment: According to the documentation, HTML in JEditorPane is restricted to HTML 3.2. But I need not to display an existing table, but create the new one in the JEditorPane. In the demo I can add rows and columns, but I need even to merge the cells.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

JUst Use HTMLEditorKit and insert desired tabel with row and col spans.
You can use the method

```
public void insertHTML(HTMLDocument doc, int offset, String html,
               int popDepth, int pushDepth,
               HTML.Tag insertTag)
```

or you can get HTMLDocument and use one of the

```
public void insertAfterStart(Element elem, String htmlText)
public void insertBeforeEnd(Element elem, String htmlText)
public void insertBeforeStart(Element elem, String htmlText)
public void insertAfterEnd(Element elem, String htmlText)
public void setOuterHTML(Element elem, String htmlText)
public void setInnerHTML(Element elem, String htmlText)
```

Comment: Ok, thanks. And can I use HTML just partially for the table only or I must use HTML for whole document, when I'm using HTMLEditorKit?